# Distributed database management system - alternatives?

Tags: database, distributed

I am working to develop an application that needs data distributed across countries. Content will be supplied "per region", but needs to be able to be easily copied to another region. On top of this I have general information that needs to be shared and synchronized across the databases.

The organisation I work for is considering implementing this system themselves, but it feels like there should be some good solutions out there already (I am open to cloud solutions - the less my company needs to manage the better)?

This might be a vague question, but I think it is possible to answer it well.

What are my options when developing this kind of distributed data system?

**Update:**

Should have elaborated (but I'm not sure how much I can say given NDA). Suffice to say, I have "Content" which I need stored on some space (files). I need metadata stored about the content distributed over several nodes (that might be hosted by us or some one else) to allow fast-paced communication and regionalized differences in data. I need to control HOW data is replicated between nodes, but preferably in a standards compliant way. (Preferably not written by us)

Answer (score 1):

You can try CouchDB. Its off-line replication model sounds like a good fit for geo distributed system.

Comment: Hm, yes, sounds interesting! I'm a bit doubtful as to whether we can go for a document oriented database though.. Is there something similar but for interrelated data?

Comment: I cannot help you with rdbmses. Usually to sync such dbs, there is yet another layer on the top of db layer. I can tell that MySQL replication doesn't work at all. Regarding couchDB, storing relational stuff is not a problem if map-reduce can handle query that you need to execute.. From alternatives, read BigTable paper (or similar) to see how google handles communication between data centers. Your system looks like global caching engine -- see how those companies handle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question - but it would really help to get more context.

You talk about "data", which usually means something with a fairly well-defined structure, often implemented in a relational database.

You also talk about "content", which usually means something with a (much) less well-defined structure, often implemented as a document of some type. Many solutions exist for structuring "documents", e.g. file systems or web sites.

Assuming we are talking about structured data, the simplest thing to do is have single repository, accessible everywhere. Have a look at "cloud" offerings - Amazon's a good bet. Creating your own global data repository is a significant undertaking - but if you're dealing with highly confidential data, or have specific performance requirements, it may the way to go.

If neither of those options work, you're in the world of "enterprise service bus". Google it, but be careful - it's a complex field, and you really want to find someone who knows what they're doing.

Having said that, using an off the shelf ESB is many times less painful than building your own distributed data structure.

Comment: See my update. But thanks for the answer, gave be a buzzphrase to google for! :) (A colleague is advocating rolling our own replicating facility sending XML-diffs to server processes that will also be written by us. These server processes will handle updating the other databases.)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's years after asking, but I was looking up the answer to the same question and it looks like **[Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)** may fit the bill.  Once setup, it looks and acts like other database solutions (Tables, Views, SQL, Transactions, etc.), but it can also be entirely decentralized.  Each instance acts as a node in a cluster of other Cassandra nodes.  They synchronize behind the scenes and if one goes down, the others pick up the slack.  This makes Cassandra both highly scalable and highly fault tolerant.